# JS spread opperator inside a map not working?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Why does this not work (using Lodash map function):

```
const data1 = [{test:"test"}];
const data2 = _.map(data1, ((item) => {...item, id:1}));
```

But this does:

```
const data3 = [{test:"test"}];
const data4 = _.map(data3, ((item) => Object.assign({}, item, {id:1})));
```

And outside the map also works:

```
const data5 = {test:"test"};
const data6 = {...data5, id:1}
```

Comment: You need to wrap your object into parenthesis, if you don't want to write a return statement. Like `=> ({...item, id:1})`

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 0):

To return an object within a map, it needs to be wrapped in `()`. So when you do `map((item) => {...item, id:1})` should be `map((item) => ({...item, id:1}))`

```
const data1 = [{test:"test"}];
const data2 = data1.map((item) => ({...item, id:1}));
console.log(data2);
```

Comment: A raw code snippet without any explanation is really low effort. At the very least you should point out what change you made. And preferably mention WHY you made that change.

Comment: @Marie You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You just have the wrong syntax when it comes to returning an a "composed" object with **ES6**. If you are using arrow functions and need to return implicitly and object you need to wrap it with `()`:

Same with `Array.map` btw. Here is the example with ES6 since lodash in this case does not play a role really.

```js
const data1 = [{test:"test"}];
const data2 = data1.map(item => ({...item, id:1}));

console.log(data2)
```

Rest is using an `Object.assign` to do the object merge for you and return it and last is just an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `const data2 = _.map(data1, ((item) => {...item, id:1}));`
Not putting `()` around the return value makes the interpreter think you are opening a block with those `{}`

Try changing it to `const data2 = _.map(data1, ((item) => ({...item, id:1})));`

Answer (score -1):

**In case of object  literal you need to do like this**

When you use `{` it is interpreted as starting braces of function than you need to use `return`.

`=>{...item, id:1}` here the `{` is interpreted as starting brace of function so spread operator will throw a error.

```js
const data1 = [{test:"test"}];
const data2 = data1.map((item) => {return{...item, id:1}});
console.log(data2);
```

**P.S**
**For the down voters who think answer is not given using loadash**

```
const data1 = [{test:"test"}];
const data2 = _.map(data1, ((item) => {return {...item, id:1}}));
```

Comment: I didn't vote down, but I think you are not using Loadash, OP's is asking for loadash map.

Comment: @carkod well this answer will be applicable whether you use loadash or not. i tried to explain concept. anywayns problem